# How do I let the user select opacity in Flash Professional CC using ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, user-input, user-interaction, flash-cc

So I was in the middle of making a type of test program where I would take parts of a shirt and the user could customize it with different colors.

While I was doing that I realized it wasn't realistic as there was absolutely no fade with the color picker tool (code shown below).

Is there any way to allow the user to use possibly a slider of some sort to change the opacity/transparency of the color(s) being used on the shirt?

```
import fl.controls.ColorPicker;
import fl.events.ColorPickerEvent;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;

var mycolor:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
cp.addEventListener(ColorPickerEvent.CHANGE,colorChanger);
function colorChanger(event:ColorPickerEvent):void{
    mycolor.color = cp.selectedColor;
    mc2.transform.colorTransform = mycolor;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add slider like this:

```
var slider:Slider=new Slider();
slider.maximum=100;
slider.value=100;
addChild(slider);
slider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.THUMB_DRAG,changeAlpha);

function changeAlpha(e:SliderEvent):void
{

    mycolor.alphaMultiplier=slider.value/100;
    mc2.transform.colorTransform = mycolor;
}
```

Comment: If you set the maximum property of the slider in your code, set ti to soemthign that applies to the situation. In this case 1.

Comment: It's giving me an error that says: 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: SliderEvent.

Comment: import flash.events.SliderEvent;

Comment: Thanks, but it still seem to be giving me the same error. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Nevermind, got it! You got the best answer and I have another question very similar pertaining to a similar topic (tint).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808925/how-do-i-allow-user-to-select-tint-amount-in-flash-professional-using-actionscri