# How do I allow user to select tint amount in Flash Professional using ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I was in the middle of making a type of test program where I would take parts of a shirt and the user could customize it with different colors.

While I was doing that I realized it wasn't realistic as there was absolutely no fade with the color picker tool (code shown below).

Is there any way to allow the user to use possibly a slider to change the level of tint on the color(s) being used on the shirt?

```
import fl.controls.ColorPicker;
import fl.events.ColorPickerEvent;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;

var mycolor:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
cp.addEventListener(ColorPickerEvent.CHANGE,colorChanger);
function colorChanger(event:ColorPickerEvent):void{
    mycolor.color = cp.selectedColor;
    mc2.transform.colorTransform = mycolor;
}


import fl.events.SliderEvent;
import fl.controls.Slider;

var slider:Slider=new Slider();
slider.maximum=100;
slider.value=100;
addChild(slider);
slider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.THUMB_DRAG,changeAlpha);

function changeAlpha(event:SliderEvent):void{
    mycolor.alphaMultiplier=slider.value/100;
    mc2.transform.colorTransform = mycolor;
}
```

Comment: http://www.flashandmath.com/howtos/tint/

Comment: @Fygo thanks! I will give you best answer if you make that comment an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this: [flashandmath.com/howtos/tint](http://flashandmath.com/howtos/tint)

Very useful site, not only for tint! It's a big shame the authors don't really update it anymore. (but they still love flash, which is cool :o) )

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use `mc2.alpha = slider.value/100` to change it.